# From a matrix of distances to a matrix of adjacency

Tags: r, distance, igraph, minimum-spanning-tree, adjacency-matrix

I have a matrix of distances 1024x1024 with all the couple of distances between all the terms. I want to define a graph starting from that. So I defined a minimum spanning tree and I computed the matrix of adjacency on that.

My matrix of distances is `distMat`.

```
matrix_of_distances <- as.matrix(distMat)
myGraph <- graph.adjacency(matrix_of_distances, weighted=TRUE)
```

My graph is a graph with all the possible arcs (because the distances between all the couple of terms are a finite value). I need another graph, sparser:

```
mst <- as.undirected(minimum.spanning.tree(myGraph))
```

From that sparse graph I can compute the matrix of adjacency with:

```
adjacency <- as_adjacency_matrix(mst, type = c("both", "upper", "lower"), attr = NULL, edges = FALSE, names = TRUE, sparse =igraph_opt("sparsematrices"))
```

Now I want to create the matrix adjacency differently, passing another minimum spanning tree object. Suppose I have created another spanning tree:

```
spt <- spantree(matrix_of_distances)
```

If I do:

```
adjacency <- as_adjacency_matrix(spt, type = c("both", "upper", "lower"), attr = NULL, edges = FALSE, names = TRUE, sparse =igraph_opt("sparsematrices"))
```

I get the error:

> Error in as_adjacency_matrix(spt, type = c("both", "upper", "lower"), 
>   :    Not a graph object

Again, I'm trying to generate a matrix of adjacency from a minimum spanning tree. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from your using function `as_adjacency_matrix` on an object of class `spantree` when it expects an `igraph`.

Since you are using `igraph`, one simple solution would be to compute the minimum spanning tree from your original "distance graph" with `igraph`'s function `mst`.

Here is how `spantree` computes the minimum spanning tree:

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
dis <- vegdist(dune)
tr <- spantree(dis)
```

The result is the following tree (`plot(tr, type="t")`)

[image]:

You could get the same result only with `igraph` functions:

```
library(igraph)
g  <- graph.adjacency(as.matrix(dis), weighted=TRUE)
g_mst <- mst(g)
```

And the resulting tree looks like this (`plot(g_mst, vertex.color=NA, vertex.size=10, edge.arrow.size=0.5)`):

[image]

Once you have your `igraph` tree, you already know that you can transform it into an adjacency matrix with function `as_adjacency_matrix`:

```
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(mst)
```